# Cannot read with `std::cin.read`: return key not recognized

Tags: c++, iostream, cin, carriage-return

I am trying to read a string from the keyboard with the `std::cin.read()` function.
What happens is that it looks like the string is being read as I type it, but the [Return] character is treated as a normal new line, and not as a terminator.

What is the terminator for this function? Is it possible to modify it?

```
#include <iostream>

char* text;
char text_length = 0;

int main() {

    std::cout << "Text length: ";
    std::cin.get(text_length);
    std::cout << "\nText length: " << text_length << std::endl;

    text = new char[1024];
    std::cout << "\n\nText: ";
    std::cin.read(text, text_length);
    std::cout << "\n\nText: " << text << std::endl;
    
    return 0;
}
```

Code tested on: GCC 11, clang 13. OS: Linux.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/read

Comment: [`std::basic_istream::read`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/read) is an **unformatted** input function. It doesn't look at the characters that it's copying. To terminate input you need to get the console to tell the application that it's reached the end of the input. On Windows that's ctrl-C; on Unix systems it's ctrl-D. To see that, you might try typing your input into a file, and redirecting the program's input to read from that file.

Comment: There is no terminator for `read`; it attempts to read as many bytes as you ask it to. You may be looking for [`getline`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/getline)

Comment: @PeteBecker On Windows console, the EOF indicator is `Ctrl+Z` (not the `Ctrl+C`, which will invoke a signal handler routine instead, which will call `ExitProcess` by default). But the problem with `Ctrl+Z` on Windows is that it has to be the first character of a separate line (i.e., you have to press `Enter` and then `Ctrl+Z`, otherwise the `Ctrl+Z` will not be recognized as an EOF). This means that the newline will also be read before EOF.

Comment: @heapunderrun — good catch on ctrl-Z.

Comment: @Pietro The `std::cin.get(text_length);` line is not doing what you expect. It treats the input as a character, not as a number. Instead, do `std::cin >> text_length;`. (Also, the `text_length` should be declared as `std::streamsize`, not as `char`).

Comment: @heapunderrun I know, in my case the length is supposed to fit in 8 bits.

Comment: @Pietro There are other bugs as well: you don't null-terminate your buffer, and you never explicitly `delete` the memory dynamically allocated by `new` (although it will be freed implicitly when the OS ends the process, of course).

Comment: @heapunderrun If you write your comment as an answer, I will accept it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Windows console, the EOF indicator is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> (not the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, which will invoke a signal handler routine instead, which will call `ExitProcess` by default). But the problem with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> on Windows is that it has to be the first character of a separate line (i.e., you have to press <kbd>Enter</kbd> and then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>, otherwise the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> will not be recognized as an EOF). This means that the newline will also be read before EOF.

The `std::cin.get(text_length);` line is not doing what you expect. It treats the input as a character, not as a number. So, if you press <kbd>5</kbd> and <kbd>Enter</kbd>, the extracted value will be 53 (the ASCII code for the character `5`). Instead, do `std::cin >> text_length;`.

Also, the `text_length` should be declared as `std::streamsize`, not as `char`. If it is supposed to fit in 8 bits, just clamp the value before further processing.

There are other bugs as well: you don't null-terminate your buffer, and you never explicitly `delete` the memory dynamically allocated by `new` (although it will be freed implicitly when the OS ends the process, of course).

To sum it up, check out this code:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>

int main()
{
    constexpr std::streamsize min_text_length{ 0 };
    constexpr std::streamsize max_text_length{ 255 };

    char* text{ nullptr };
    std::streamsize text_length{ 0 };

    std::cout << "Enter text length: ";
    std::cin >> text_length;
    std::cin.clear();
    std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
    std::cout << "Text length entered: " << text_length << '\n';

    text_length = std::clamp(text_length, min_text_length, max_text_length);
    std::cout << "Text length to be used: " << text_length << '\n';

    text = new char[max_text_length + 1]{}; // Note this zero-fills the buffer
    std::cout << "Enter text: ";
    std::cin.read(text, text_length);
    std::cout << "Text entered BEGINS-->" << text << "<--ENDS\n";

    delete[] text;
}
```

After entering the length, enter some text, and when finished, press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, followed by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>, and <kbd>Enter</kbd> again. (As already mentioned, the newline character preceding the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> will unfortunately be read in as well, but at least the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> allows you to terminate the input.)